# Passbook - Hardcoding locations in JSON works but not passing variable

Tags: php, html, arrays, json, passbook

I am using a pre-built structure found [here](https://github.com/tschoffelen/PHP-PKPass) to create Apple Passbook passes.  I'm using the starbucks example but with different parameters.

***Background:*** Apple only allows 10 locations to be saved to a pass.  The purpose of saving locations is it triggers a phone notification when you are near.

The flow of my system is:

- User inputs home address
- google retrieves exact coordinates lat/lng
- lat and lng are set to the form's hidden inputs and are POSTed to pass creation PHP.
- server queries for 10 nearest locations and adds their positions to the pass JSON.
- pass creates and downloads

**Problem**

It's possible it's a problem with PHP or Passbook.

POSTed variables query in the Mysql just fine.  In testing the JSON, the JSON matches the target pattern given in documentation exampled below.  The 10 nearest stores do indeed insert themselves in correct syntax.  However, Passes that had their locations hardcoded in the JSON

```
    'locations' => array(

        array(
            'longitude' => 123456,
            'latitude' => 123456,
            'relevantText' => 'You are near store'
            )
        )
```

These show up in map locations.

Passes who had their locations set with variables in any way, such as

```
    'locations' => array(

        array(
            'longitude' => $lng,
            'latitude' => $lat,
            'relevantText' => 'You are near store'
            )
        )
```

Does not show their locations on the map.
I have tried mixing both approaches, and sure enough, only hardcoded locations show up - variable-submitted lats and lngs get ignored.

Right before the final pass creation step, I get a location formula like:

```
"locations":[
{"longitude":-XX.XXXX,"latitude":XX.XXXX,"relevantText":"PLACE NAME"},
...(ten times.. comma'd until last one)...
]
```

Which can be compared to the target formula in [apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/Creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH4-SW53):

```
"locations" : [
    {"latitude" : 37.3229, "longitude" : -122.0323, "relevantText" : "Store nearby on 3rd and Main."}
]
```

I don't understand why variables can be passed fine, query fine, enter JSON fine, but make a distinction in what the pass file does.

---

**EDIT:  More information on request.**
The HTML form on index that passes the lat/lng given from google geocode.

```
<form action="pass.php" method="post">   
        <fieldset>       
        <input type='text' id='lat' name='lat' value='' > //set thru jquery
        <input type='text' id='lng' name='lng' value='' > //set thru jquery      
        <input type="submit" class="btn primary" name='pass' id='passButton' value=" Create pass &gt; " disabled />
        </fieldset>
</form>
```

**the pass.php that generates pass:**

```
<?php
require('PKPass/PKPass.php');

$lat = floatval($_POST['lat']);
$lng = floatval($_POST['lng']);

require_once ('../../functions.php'); //get mysql wrapper class


$query = "SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * 
cos( radians( longitude ) - radians($lng) ) + sin( radians($lat) ) * 
sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM dealers HAVING
distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 10;";

$result = $db->doQuery($query); //wrapper class helps do queries
$pass = new PKPass\PKPass();


$pass->setCertificate('cert/pass.p12');
$pass->setCertificatePassword('PASSWORD');
$pass->setWWDRcertPath('cert/AppleWWDRCA.pem');

// Top-Level Keys 
$standardKeys         = array(
    'description'        => 'Demo pass',
    'formatVersion'      => 1,
    'organizationName'   => 'NAME',
    'passTypeIdentifier' => 'pass.place.coupon',
    'serialNumber'       => '123456',
    'teamIdentifier'     => 'IDENTIFIER'
);
$associatedAppKeys    = array();
$relevanceKeys        = array(
    'locations' => array(

    )  

);

while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {

    $array = 
            array(
         'longitude' => sprintf("%.4f", floatval($row->longitude)),
         'latitude' => sprintf("%.4f",floatval($row->latitude)),
        'relevantText' => $row->name
   );

    $relevanceKeys['locations'][] = $array;

}


$styleKeys            = array(

    'coupon' => array(
    'primaryFields' => array(
      array(
        'key' => 'offer',
        'label' => 'ITEM',
        'value' => 'FREE'
      )
    ),

    'auxiliaryFields' => array(
      array(
        'key' => 'expires',
        'label' => 'EXPIRES',
        'value' => '2018-04-24T10:00-05:00',
        'isRelative' => true,
        'dateStyle' => 'PKDateStyleShort'
      )
    )
  )
);

$visualAppearanceKeys = array(
    'barcode'         => array(
        'format'          => 'PKBarcodeFormatPDF417',
//        'format'          => 'PKBarcodeFormatQR',
        'message'         => 'MESSAGE',
        'messageEncoding' => 'iso-8859-1'
    ),
//    'foregroundColor' => 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
    'backgroundColor' => 'rgb(39,81,154)',
    'logoText'        => 'COMPANY'
);
$webServiceKeys       = array();

// Merge all pass data and set JSON for $pass object
$passData = array_merge(
    $standardKeys,
    $associatedAppKeys,
    $relevanceKeys,
    $styleKeys,
    $visualAppearanceKeys,
    $webServiceKeys
);

$pass->setJSON(json_encode($passData));

// Add files to the PKPass package
$pass->addFile('icon.png');
$pass->addFile('icon@2x.png');
$pass->addFile('logo.png');

if(!$pass->create(true)) { // Create and output the PKPass
    echo 'Error: '.$pass->getError();
}
```

Obvious things in caps are omissions.

**Resulting JSON:**

```
        {"description":"Demo pass","formatVersion":1,"organizationName":"NAME","passTypeIdentifier":"pass.place.coupon","serialNumber":"123456","teamIdentifier":"IDENTIFIER","locations":[{"longitude":"-xx.xxxx","latitude":"xx.xxxx","relevantText":"STORE_1"},{"longitude":"-xx.xxxx","latitude":"xx.xxxx","relevantText":"STORE_2"},{"longitude":"-xx.xxxx","latitude":"xx.xxxx","relevantText":"STORE_3"},{"longitude":"-xx.xxxx","latitude":"xx.xxxx","relevantText":"STORE_4"},{"longitude":"-xx.xxxx","latitude":"xx.xxxx","relevantText":"STORE_5"},{"longitude":"-xx.xxxx","latitude":"xx.xxxx","relevantText":"STORE_6"},{"longitude":"-xx.xxxx","latitude":"xx.xxxx","relevantText":"STORE_7"},{"longitude":"-xx.xxxx","latitude":"xx.xxxx","relevantText":"STORE_8"},{"longitude":"-xx.xxxx","latitude":"xx.xxxx","relevantText":"STORE_9"},{"longitude":"-xx.xxxx","latitude":"xx.xxxx","relevantText":"STORE_10"}],"coupon":{"primaryFields":[{"key":"offer","label":"ITEM","value":"FREE"}],"auxiliaryFields":[{"key":"expires","label":"EXPIRES","value":"2018-04-24T10:00-05:00","isRelative":true,"dateStyle":"PKDateStyleShort"}]},"barcode":{"format":"PKBarcodeFormatPDF417","message":"MESSAGE","messageEncoding":"iso-8859-1"},"backgroundColor":"rgb(39,81,154)","logoText":"COMPANY"}
```

Obviously, xx.xxxx values being real numbers.  The fact that they are strings or numbers does not seem to have mattered.  When I hardcoded them, they were strings.
The above JSON does not make a pass file with map locations, when it will if the lat/lng were hardcoded.
Tested on PassWallet, works.  On iO6 simulator, it says "Safari cannot download this file."  When I have gotten it to use passes before.

Comment: Can you post the actual JSON being produced, together with your PHP code.  With out either of these, it is impossible to diagnose your problem.

Comment: @PassKit okay, I have added much more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a strange scope error.

All the calculations and creating the JSON would appear to be fine, but somewhere inbetween setting the JSON and creating the pass it would no longer have the POST variables intact.  They would default to 0/0, somewhere near Africa.

I was able to solve this by using session variables instead of GET/POST.  Before the form submits, I'd jquery ajax set the session variables and then call them in the pass creation page, doing whatever calculations with it that I needed to derive the 10 additional lat/lngs.  If the starting variable no longer exists, can't derive the rest!

Just posting this here in case someone has the same problem.  It might be sort of unique to this project, but that's how it went.

Answer (score 1):

With the additional information, your problem is clear.

> The fact that they are strings or numbers does not seem to have
>   mattered.

Actually for Passbook it does matter.  Passbook is meticulously picky over type. `sprintf("%.4f", floatval($row->longitude))` is casting your query results as strings, where the package format requires a double.

From the [Passbook Package Format Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/Introduction.html):

[image]

No need to format to any particular number of places, just throw in the raw float values and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, but I have had this problem for awhile and the sprintf part of the code was a recent installment.  It's still good to know that it's picky for a double.  I still get the same problem removing the sprintf.

Comment: Do you think it has something to do with the query not finishing in time to make the variables for the pass to get created?

Comment: If it works on PassWallet, then the correct alues are coming in as expected, it appears that they are just incorrectly formatted for iOS.  If you remove your sprintf and it is still not working, then it is likely a problem with your query output.  Try examining the JSON to check that it contains float values, and that those values are valid coordinates for your test locations.  Also check the device logs in Xcode as you install the pass.  This may give you some clues as to why values are being ignored.

Comment: with the sprintf change I realize I did get iO6 to recognize the pass.  ( I don't use apple much, so I wasn't sure how to check locations on a live pass in passbook.  But I can in PassWallet's UI. )  I will continue debugging and see what I can come up with

Comment: Just check your JSON, if they are floats and correct and the pass is ingesting into Passbook, then you are probably good to go.  Also you might want to check out this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.passesalliance.wallet.  Every bit as good as PassWallet but without the ads.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I tried it.  It seems to replicate the passbook UI closer.  It seems PassWallet is the only one that allows the user to view the offer locations on a map, so I'm unsure if it's a PassWallet problem.

Comment: For the Passes Android app, flip the pass then click the more button (in top left) an then map to see the locations on a map.  Passbook on iOS does not let you see locations.  The only way to know if it is working is to physically visit the location.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice that! It will help in comparing the app location results.